# How to get split screen vertical scrolling for angular app?

Tags: angular, vertical-scrolling, angular-template, split-screen

I have a page, the left half is a dashboard with thumbnails and the right half is a map. My issue is that as I get more entries the dashboard increases and the whole page scrolls, instead of just the dashboard. I want it to work like the Airbnb booking page, parallel side by side scrolling. I have tried using overflow in css but somehow still doesn't work.

this is the html of the component that displays the two aspects, map and dashboard.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <app-artwork-dashboard class="col-lg-5 mt-3 scroll" #list (add)="input.startAddingArtwork()" (edit)="input.startEditingArtwork($event)">    </app-artwork-dashboard>
    <app-open-street-map class="col-lg-7 map-shadow"></app-open-street-map>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here the css:

```
.scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

on the dashboard i have a scroll class which should technically make that side of the page scroll-able, at least I thought so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your case:

```
.container{max-width:50%;  width:50%; float:left; height:100vh; overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: scroll; overflow:scroll;}

<div class="container"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
<div class="container"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

Or you can use flex to wrap div to set them side by side and style box as below:

```
.wrap{display:flex;}
.box{
height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
    overflow: scroll;
}

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">

  </div>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution with inline-block:

```
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 49%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
```